# Color the specific range of word by NSMutableAttributedString in a UITextView cause UITextView scroll to the top?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, nsmutableattributedstring, contentoffset

Here is a UITextView,on which i put long chapter(i wanna to make it just like a book.),when i press a word more than 2 seconds,(i set a long gesture here),then the word will be highlight(the following code can successfully hightlight the word,but also trigger some side effect which i need to eliminate),then here comes the story:

code is like follows:

```
   NSMutableAttributedString *attrStr = [self.contentTextView.attributedText mutableCopy];
   [attrStr addAttribute:NSBackgroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor grayColor] range: _wordToSearchRange ];
   self.contentTextView.attributedText = attrStr;
```

So far, i debugged the code, and finally targetted on this line:

```
   self.contentTextView.attributedText = attrStr;
```

which lead my textView scroll to the top(not stay in the current word location),it is reasonable since this operation is similar to refresh the textView and set the totally new content for it. But is there any other method to set the specific word range in a textView which would not cause this ?

Any help would be great!  Thx a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are editing existing text, you shouldn't replace all of it. 
You need to create attributes dictionary and add it to the attributed text:

```
NSMutableDictionary* attributes; //set the wanted attributes
NSRange range; //set the right range

[_contentTextView.textStorage beginEditing];
[_contentTextView.textStorage addAttributes:attributes range:range];
[_contentTextView.textStorage endEditing];
```

Comment: thx bro,i just try this, it causes the same result -- the textView will scroll to the top..